# JPanels keep appearing as little squares no matter what size I set

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JFrame class with a BorderLayout that holds another class (ScorePanel) which extends JPanel. This is the relevant code for the JFrame class, a method not called by the constructor that sets up the ScorePanels. gPanel is the main game panel, but don't worry about that.:

```
public void initialize() { //called by controller at the end
    if (Controller.DEBUG) System.out.println("View initialized"); 
    JPanel scores = new JPanel();
    scores.setSize(1000,200);
    scores.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    ScorePanel score1 = new ScorePanel("Volume", 1);
    ScorePanel score2 = new ScorePanel("Pitch", 2);
    scores.add(score1); scores.add(score2);
    scores.setVisible(true);
    scores.validate();
    this.add(scores, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(gpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); //main game panel
    this.validate();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.repaint();
}
```

And this is the relevant code of ScorePanel:

```
private int score; //this current score
private String name; //this name
private int player; //this player

public ScorePanel(String n, int p){ //a JPanel that shows the player's name and score
    super();
    name = n;
    score = 0;
    player = p;
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setSize(450,150);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

I've figured this out before, but I can't remember what to do. What happens when I run this is I see a few white squares where the large ScorePanels should be.

Here is a screenshot. I hope my question and code is clear.

[image: Unfinished pong game]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` by default which respects preferred sizes of its child components. It's likely that the current preferred size is `0 x 0`. Override `getPreferredSize` to set this.

```
ScorePanel score1 = new ScorePanel("Volume", 1) {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(150, 100);
    };
};
```

Don't use `setSize` on components. Rather set preferred sizes as above and make sure to invoke [JFrame#pack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29).